# Trust store management best practice

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

A typical scenario: a big company with lots of servers in all shapes and colors (on-premise, private and public cloud)

Each server (or rather each service) needs to maintain a trust store (a file in Java, or a file folder in Node.JS) that contains certificates required to establish SSL/TLS connections to other (mostly internal) services

Certificates change, get recalled, expire, - all that introduces service maintenance overhead

I'm looking for a software or an approach that would shift certificate maintenance from the service teams to the more appropriate group (e.g. information security)

Answer (score 4):

Typically, one maintains a (mostly offline) root CA and then signs a certain number of intermediates to actually issue end-entity certificates.  With this approach, you ship the root CA in the certificate package for your system using a configuration management approach (e.g., on Debian, a custom `ca-certificates` package distributed via Puppet).

As for the end-entity keys and certificates, usually these can be distributed via something like Vault.  Vault, in fact, [has support for running your own PKI](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/pki-engine).  It can also be used to ship globally trusted certs to systems.  You can automatically deploy systems every *N* days to rotate keys (or otherwise guarantee frequent deployments or certificate reloads); that can easily be handled by service teams as a requirement for deployment.  The certificate management can be done with Vault or other secret-handling tooling by the security team.